# Rails4: losing form validation errors while using `redirect_to` in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I've been trying to fix this for a while but haven't gotten anywhere yet. Would appreciate if someone could let me know how how this can be done, or if there is any way i can use the `render` method to do this instead (currently preserves errors but redirects to wrong path as mentioned below...)
I have a custom route for form which I am trying to redirect back when there are validation errors:

```
get "clubs/sign_up/:plan_id", to: "clubs#new", as: :new_membership
```

below is what I have so far in my controller along along with some comments regarding other steps I have tried

`clubs_controller.rb`

```
def create

    @membership = Membership.new(membership_params)

    if @membership.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please check form errors:"
      redirect_to new_membership_path(session[:membership_plan_id]) #errors lost
      # render action: 'new', plan_id: 'silver' # <<<Preserves errors but breaks path, renders: localhost:3000/clubs instead of .../clubs/sign_up/:plan_id
      # session[:membership_errors] = @membership.errors #<<< Doesn't wotk either, getting a cookie overflow error when trying to pass errors to #new
      return
    end
  end

def new
    session[:membership_plan_id] = params[:plan_id]
    @membership = Membership.new
end
```

Comment: Can you share your new method?

Comment: @Tim updated, not much in it though. Also realised using `render` might not work because you would be in the create path with the new's view rendered, which is why the path is wrong.so it would have to be done using redirect_to

Comment: OK, I'd recommend getting render working - that's the normal way, that the render path looks odd is normal, render does not actually run your controller action, nor use your routes, it just calls the template. So the path you describe is fine. The trick is to set up your variables to match the conditions that the new method leaves it in when it calls the template. Are you using any other variables, like param[:plan_I'd] in the view?

Comment: @Tim i have param[:plan_id] used in the view along with my form, but thats about it

Comment: OK, last question, is plan_id part of your membership model?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming plan_I'd is part of your model..

Change your render line to:

```
render :new
```

Change the rest to:

```
def new
  session[:membership_plan_id] = params[:plan_id]
  @membership = Membership.new plan_id: params[:plan_id]
end

def create

  @membership = Membership.new(membership_params)

  if @membership.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:error] = @membership.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    render :new
  end
end
```

And add a hidden field for plan_id in your form. The reason render goes wrong is that it does not have the param available, trying to add it to the render operation does not work hence your issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to render instead of redirecting. Use the `||=` operator to help here.. It's all just ruby, so something like

```
(..snip..)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Problem with form"
    new
  end
end

def new
  session[:membership_plan_id] = params[:plan_id]
  @membership ||= Membership.new
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: explanation: within the 'create' method, we just run 'new' instead of performing a render. then the 'new' method specifically calls render (so it won't try to render 'create' in the create action) and we already have @membership from create, so it won't make a new variable and thus clear your errors.